# Standardization of a REST API using swagger core and swagger UI

Tags: java, json, rest, swagger

I am trying to standardize a very basic REST Service made using jax-rs that converts temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice-a-versa. The class I am trying to standardize contains a simple code for converting temperature. I am trying to incorporate Swagger-Core to create a JSON file but the JSON file created is not in the Swagger syntax. The reason is that the swagger annotations I am using are not creating the JSON file , instead the JSON is created by the the return statement of the method. I have tried several approaches but in vain.Is there an issue with the annotations being used or is the create JSONObject ovveriding the Swagger part?

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import io.swagger.annotations.*;

@Api
@SwaggerDefinition(
    info = @Info(
            description = "My API",
            version = "V1.2.3",
            title = "The only API you'll ever need to learn about me",
            termsOfService = "share and care",
            contact = @Contact(name = "Sponge-Bob", email = "sponge-bob@swagger.io", url = "http://swagger.io"),
            license = @License(name = "Apache 2.0", url = "http://www.apache.org")
            ),
    consumes = {"application/json" },
    produces = {"application/json" },
    schemes = {SwaggerDefinition.Scheme.HTTP,      SwaggerDefinition.Scheme.HTTPS},
    externalDocs = @ExternalDocs(value = "About me", url = "http://about.me/me"))

@Path("/ftocservice")



@Produces({"application/json"})

public class FtoCService {

@GET

  public Response convertFtoC() throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    Double fahrenheit = 98.24;
    Double celsius;
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32)*5/9; 
    jsonObject.put("FtoC", celsius);
    String result = ""+jsonObject;
    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
  }
```